# Cannot understand this MATLAB syntax?

Tags: matlab

```
for i=0:255
m(i+1)=sum((0:i)'.*p(1:i+1)); end
```

What is happening can anyone explain. p is an array of size 256 elements same as m.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p = (0:255)';
m = zeros(1,256);
for i=0:255
    m(i+1)=sum((0:i)'.*p(1:i+1)); 

end
```

`m[i+1]` contains the scalar product of `[0,1,2,..,i]` with `(p[1],...,p[i+1])`

You can write it as :

```
p = (0:255);
m = zeros(1,256);
for i=0:255
    m(i+1)=sum((0:i).*p(1:i+1)); 

end
```

Or:

```
p = (0:255);
m = zeros(1,256);
for i=0:255
    m(i+1)=(0:i)*p(1:i+1)'; 

end
```

In case you don't recall, that is the definition of [scalar product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the `p` is, you can calculate `m` by:

```
dm = (0 : length(p) - 1)' .* p(:); % process as column vector
m = cumsum(dm);
```

Hint: write the formula for m[n], then for m[n+1], then subtract to get the formula:

```
m[n+1] - m[n] = (n - 1) * p[n]
```

and this is `dm`.